# How do we handle migrations from other sites currently, and how do we want to handle them?

Tags: discussion, migration

Recently, I spoke with the Programmers mods about migrations from Programmers to Workplace, and the rejection rate is about 40%. We definitely gain a lot of good content from Programmers. It's *awesome* that the Programmers community thinks of our site and helping users find answers, but I also think we can reduce the amount of posts that get closed after migration to our site.

What should we ask other sites to do prior to migrations:

1. Check with a moderator?
2. Ask in the Water Cooler?
3. Something else?

Also, the Programmers mods asked if we can write a meta post with some brief guidelines on how to tell if a question with a programming slant would be a good fit for our site. What are the main points we should highlight?

Comment: That last part is important. The five of us can easily check with you guys before we migrate anything, but we have quite a few users who'll keep flagging (and worse: commenting) any career related question for migration. We need your help to educate the wider ProgSE community on what questions you welcome (and what you could live without).

Comment: Adding on to what @Yannis said, I generally get a ping from P.SE on this too if I'm idling in chat and there's a "go to workplace!" comment which is out of place. If I do, I try to respond with a "Actually..." type comment which I then drop in P.SE chat and it gets upvoted. This works, ok, again only when people are around on chat though.

Comment: @yannis - You can always leave a comment in chat with a link to the question.  When someone pops in and sees an action item like that they can help address it and then ping you back.

Answer (score 7):

The main issue I have with migrated posts is that they can't be closed and then edited (the migration gets rejected and they get sent back). To prevent this unfortunate occurrence, I would suggest:

1. If someone on Programmers understands TWP, they should **edit it prior to migration**
2. If nobody on Programmers understands TWP, they should ask in the Water Cooler for someone to edit it (and be around to approve the edit)
3. If nobody is around in the Water Cooler, they should use best judgment

For instance, [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18544/liability-for-company-development-equipment) could have been edited to change it from, *"Can they do that?"* to *"How can I negotiate to avoid that?"* [This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18138/how-many-hours-do-you-expect-to-clock-in-a-40-hour-week) would have been a good fit if it were changed from, *"How many hours do you guys log?"* to *"How do you handle non-work hours like lunches or meetings when allotting manpower?"* or something of the like.

Since there is a lack of community consensus on [when and how to edit](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2168/), these questions have a higher chance to become missed opportunities if they get closed after being migrated (yes, I know we can flag you and you can unilaterally revoke the lock). A far better approach is to edit them prior to coming over, so that they get received well -- it will also get users more interested in our community if they see what our community standards are and aren't welcomed by downvotes and/or close votes.

Ideally whoever migrates the post can do the edit on the Programmer's side. If not, they should come to The Water Cooler and ask if someone can do it. If there isn't anyone around and they are impatient, they should use their best judgment.

Comment: Pretty much in agreement, the only thing I would add is that things don't 'need to be migrated right away!!!' if people aren't around to help out there is no harm in leaving us a message in the cooler and keeping it on their site (even if on hold) until someone, mod, user, whatever can make a judgement / edit. I would also point out that we in the cooler might not always be right, and that a migration shouldn't be migrated / rejected on the advice of a single user alone! Some users are better at seeing hidden potential than others.

Comment: I think number 3 should be if no one is around then they should wait until someone is or get approval from a mod.

Comment: In reality, people are going to migrate stuff without 'approval'. I would much rather that they at least think about whether it is appropriate before doing it rather than auto-migrate due to flags. Yes, asking is always better, but at the very least, judgment should be exercised.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm lurking in the p.se chat they ask me nearly 100% of the time prior to a migration.

I generally am very candid on my thoughts regarding question quality and acceptance here.

This seems to work most of the time?

Comment: Then why do we still get so many bad questions migrated.

Comment: @chad as it turns out I don't live there 100% of the time ;)

Comment: So then you need to change your life so that you can...