# Would questions regarding medical residency be in scope?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

In the USA, residency training is a period of time where recently graduated doctors work and train under senior doctors to gain specialized skills in their medical specialty such as anesthetics, emergency care etc.

I have a friend working in second year residency in a major hospital near where I live. Given residency training is similar to "regular work" in other environments in that people are supervised, trained,and evaluated based on criteria, would questions during residencies be in scooe here? The specific situation of my friend pertains to clinical patient care.

I will wait to post question until determination is made.

Comment: You can also share the question or phrasing you want to ask so we can give a more specific answer, if you want

Comment: It's basically how to cope with a situation they disagree with, sharing of ventilators due to shortage,  and lack of support during night time shifts so very little senior suppory

Comment: So far what you describe sounds good to me. I'd say you go for it, we can edit if improvement is needed.

Comment: Coping with certain workplace interactions tends to be on-topic here and that doesn't change whether it's an internship, residency or "regular" job. Do be careful in making sure there's an answerable question and it's not a rant in disguise. Also keep in mind that if medical decision making becomes involved (i.e. managing limited resources, interpersonal disagreements that relate to patient care or ethical problems, ...) that could push it far enough out of our typical area that it could become off-topic.

Comment: A potential test would be if you could swap the specific concepts with something more mundane without changing the core of the question. If you can swap ventilators for forklifts and night shift at a hospital to night shift in a warehouse with a skeleton crew without enough managers present and the question still makes sense then it's a workplace issue. If you can't without *drastically* changing potential answers we might [need doctors](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2267/25739) to answer it which could mean it's off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say **yes, they are on scope.**

Residencies are in a way like Internships, as a rough analogy. Of course it also depends on what question you plan to ask about, but in general terms I consider Residencies valid Workplace environments (they are carried in a Hospital, the Resident reports to somebody, etc.).

Comment: Agreed, on topic.