# What's the problem with the 'Are performance bonuses a scam' question, and can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, editing

[Are discretionary bonuses in finance roles essentially scams?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/24289/are-discretionary-bonuses-in-finance-roles-essentially-scams)

I personally thought that this was a great question, leading to good discussion about the nature of corporate/finance work culture and how bonuses are paid.

I suspect the reason that it's being downvoted is the opinionated tone of the original question. As Joe S put it:

> From your words ("scam", "dupe" "absurd"), it seems as if you have
>   already drawn your own conclusion. Try to confirm that with your boss
>   rather than just assuming. Then decide what you want to do about it
>   (if anything), other than just be unhappy.

Can this question be edited to put it in more objective terms and make it a good question?

Answer (score 7):

It was closed because it was 'primarily opinion-based' according to the community as stated in the banner below:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

From my perspective, this is not a good fit for our site because it goes against several of the guidelines for having good subjective questions listed in our [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

1. there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
2. your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

The author spends the first 5 paragraphs explaining his distaste for how the system currently works. The last paragraph contains a question which I read as, *"So that's how our crappy bonus system works, how can I get the bonus without doing the stuff that my company awards bonuses for?"* How can we answer that?

The information provided to scope the question is in direct disagreement with the desired result. And I think that the asker, who is presumably quite intelligent, sees the disconnect and is venting with a rant thinly disguised as a question.

[Real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) and as-posed, there are no good answers to this question because of the way it was phrased.

If you can see a question that doesn't fall in to that trap, I invite you to [make an aggressive edit to the question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2153/aggressive-edits).