# Why the close votes?

Tags: discussion

My question [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/28241/my-manager-thinks-showing-up-early-doesnt-show-as-much-enthusiasm-as-staying-la/30385#30385) has already attracted 3 close votes but I am completely confused as to why. If someone has left a comment concerning it, I can't tell because every comment has been deleted. I'm pretty confused because judging by the community's reaction this question is very relevant and has even been edited by someone to put the most relevant points right at the top.

Comment: Most of the close votes predate the edits, so that might be part of it.  Moderators don't generally remove comments that provide feedback on improving the post (that's what comments are mainly *for*, after all), unless a subsequent edit has rendered them obsolete.  I haven't looked at the details of this case yet (hence comment rather than answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the comments explain why, and I can't offer any insight beyond all three votes were issued for the following reason:

> **[Real questions have answers.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)** Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, click [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696).

My assumption (bearing in mind that I didn't cast a vote) is that your question strikes many people as a general complaint about your situation without indicating what exactly you want to do to improve the situation. As a result they may be under the impression that you are ranting rather than asking a question that can be answered/solved.

More specifically, you are basically saying, *"Me and my manager have a difference of opinion -- who's right?"* which isn't exactly the most actionable of questions (determining who is right won't solve the problem).

Right now the question is still open, and you've gotten 12 answers. Even if it does get closed, you have gotten *far* more eyes and responses to your question than most on the site. I don't see a huge problem that needs action, but hopefully someone else will pop in and explain their reasoning for your reference when asking questions in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the evaluation, that's what I was looking for. The way you explain it makes sense, I can edit it to make it more actionable so perhaps it won't attract the two more votes left before it closes.