# Phrasing a question about technical leadership readiness

Tags: discussion

I'd like to pose a question, which goes something like this:

'What are some signs that one is ready for a technical leadership role'

or

'How does one know that they're ready for a technical leadership role'

Does this sound like it'd be a fit here? If not, is there a way to phrase the question so it'd work?

Comment: ["what skills should I learn?"](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695/168)

Comment: You might enjoy this book: http://www.amazon.com/Becoming-Technical-Leader-Gerald-Weinberg-ebook/dp/B004J4VV3I/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?_encoding=UTF8&sr=8-1&qid=1436393381

Answer (score 2):

I think if it focuses more on the *leadership* part and less on the *technical* part, that kind of question will work here.  You should specify the role more -- does it entail becoming a supervisor?  Interacting with new parts of the organization or customers?  Responsibility for a budget?  I know what "technical lead" means in *my* company but it might not be the same in yours.

Part of your question is presumably about evaluating technical proficiency.  We can't answer questions like "how do I know if I'm a good-enough programmer?" or "[what skills should I learn?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695)", but we can handle questions about evaluating technical skill more broadly.  In fact, we've had those as interview-related questions, so look around there for inspiration.

Finally, you should specify in the question whether you're talking about yourself or one of your employees (e.g. if you're a manager considering promoting someone).  The perspectives, and tools available, are likely to be different.

Comment: You should definitely describe the role, and maybe add more info, like areas you/he/she is already familiar with, etc, otherwise the question will attract 'too broad' close votes.