# Why "Does it make sense to apply to second time for another position?" has been closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/67841/does-it-make-sense-to-apply-to-second-time-for-another-position) has been closed as off topic. I do not think it is:

- The question about the job search should be on topic.
- It is unlikely that it is not clear what is being asked (should I re-apply or not)?
- The expected answer would be yes or no, maybe with some comments. It is not too broad.
- Even if the answer is "depends", with only two alternatives would be possible to give some hints, when and which alternative applies.

I have posted the comment saying the reason of closing is not clear to me. The explanation is somewhat along the lines "poorly worded", but I think it is sufficiently clear and way of wording should not make the question off topic anyway.

I do not actually think the question should have been closed. Please comment.

Comment: I suppose, it might be because your question was not really clear for a lot of people. Wording it differently might cause the reopening.

Comment: I've edited your question again (see comment there) and voted to reopen.

Comment: I put in the 5th reopen vote.  You are back in business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link in the close reason:

> > Questions asking for **advice on what to do are not [practical answerable
> >     questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)** (e.g.
> >     *"what job should I take?"*, or *"what skills should I learn?"*). Questions should get answers explaining *why* and *how* to make a
> >     decision, not advice on what to do. For more information, click
> >     [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695).
>
> Our goal here at The Workplace is to help out people in the future who
>   are facing the same problem. When people ask us for personalized
>   advice, a lot of the specific details will not apply to other people
>   who come across the question since their details may be slightly
>   different and they can't determine whether or not the answer is
>   appropriate for their situation.
>
> Questions about what decision to make are best asked to your friends
>   and family, or maybe Facebook. You can always try asking in our
>   [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler)
>   where the rules are quite a bit more relaxed. Sometimes talking
>   through a decision can help, so it's best to pick a format designed
>   for that sort of back-and-forth discussion. The Workplace is [not that
>   place though](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour).
>
> Another alternative is to
>   [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your post to
>   ask about *why* and *how* you should make the decision, rather than
>   just *what* decision to make. For instance, instead of asking *"Should
>   I take the job in the big multi-national company or the up-and-coming
>   startup?"* you could ask a question that will help you make that
>   decision, like *"How can I figure out the financial health of a
>   startup I am applying to by asking questions in an interview?"*

Your question is, "Should I apply for a second job in a company that has already passed me over for another position?" -- none of us can help you make the decision on whether or not you should do that (that's your choice).

What you should do instead is explain what your goal is (do you want to improve your chance of getting this job? do you want to make sure you keep a good relationship with the company in the future? etc.), and then explain what circumstances are making it difficult for you to accomplish that goal. For instance:

> I recently applied to a job with a large company (500 employees) and made it past the final round of the interview as the second choice candidate. The person selected over me accepted the job and so I did not get an offer.
>
> The same company has now listed another job in another department that requires similar skills. I don't have any experience applying for two positions at the same company, and want to leverage my successful interviews for the previous positions. I'm not sure if I'm expected to apply normally and trust that they will share information about my previous application, or whether I should contact the HR person who handled the last interview, or something else.
>
> How can I use the previous interview process as an asset while applying for this new position?

This specifically states what you're trying to do (improve your chances of getting a job you had a successful interview with), and it explains why you're not sure how to proceed (you don't know whether or not HR will be sharing information amongst themselves in cases like this). The question is clear and will be helpful to other people.

See the difference?

Comment: Ok. I will rewrite the question header to match the idea behind this commend and will notify for reopening.