# "Choose rationally between two different jobs" - reopen request

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reopen-request

The question **[Chose rationally between two different jobs (life changing)](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/76709/chose-rationally-between-two-different-jobs-life-changing)** has been closed for asking "What to do". I believe that this question is not off-topic and should be reopened.

The final lines from the question ask

> I'm trying to find a way to decide semi-rationally: at the moment I'm
>   listing all the pro and cons and weighting them on a -5/+5 scale.
>   However I feel like, if I am the one to write down pro and cons it
>   will be an important bias in the final result.
>
> What's the most rational way to decide which road to take?

This question is not asking us to make a decision for the OP. The question is asking how to make a rational choice, which is exactly what we want! The [Meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695) specifically says,

> Another alternative is to
>   [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/editing) your post to
>   ask about *why* and *how* you should make the decision, rather than
>   just *what* decision to make. For instance, instead of asking *"Should
>   I take the job in the big multi-national company or the up-and-coming
>   startup?"* you could ask a question that will help you make that
>   decision, like *"How can I figure out the financial health of a
>   startup I am applying to by asking questions in an interview?"*

I would like to request that this question be reopened.

Comment: Good to note that his final question could be interpreted as "What analysis techniques could I use to rationalise a decision of this importance?" or "How can I make a rational decision based on the evidence I have and my fear of bias?"

Comment: I was one of the VTC.  you make a strong argument.I'll consider your argument overnight.

Comment: It's been reopened.