# Why is this question on hold? Complaining about junior label after entering company

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The following question was put on hold

[Is it reasonable to complain about the 'junior' label after entering the company with 4 years of experience?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85862/is-it-reasonable-to-complain-about-the-junior-label-after-entering-the-company)

for the following reason:

> Questions seeking advice on **company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies** should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking **legal advice** should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695).

The reason for placing this as off-topic is to say the question should be asked towards the HR department or a lawyer.

However the question was : **would it be reasonable and/or appropriate to bring this up with HR or my team lead, or is it better to wait for my six month evaluation?**

I don't know about you guys, but I'm not going to ask my HR department whether I should complain to them now or in 6 months.

Putting this question to off-topic is an awnser in itself, it's litterally telling him to go to HR. Which should be posted as an awnser not as a flag :p .

If the question is off-topic, I'd expect a different off-topic reason?

Comment: I believe that those 3 sentences are 3 different (if related) close reasons and here the second one applies: whether it makes sense to complain about titles in this specific situation at this specific company is not something we can figure out. For "*Can I use sick leave as regular PTO?*" sentence 1 applies. "*Will I be sent home immediately if I give notice?*" falls under sentence 2 since you obviously can't ask HR for this. Whenever you need in-depth knowledge of particulars to make a reasonable attempt at answering this is the close reason that tends to be used.

Comment: I would have voted to close with the same reason, though my reasoning would have been that the OP's first step to take is to contact HR about what is most likely a simple clerical error, which would render the entire question moot.

Comment: @Lilienthal So to make this more clear for myself. You're saying the question comes down to "should I ask HR about this possible error they made?". Which would then indeed decided by the severity of the error, which happens to be subjective and cannot be awnsered by us. and therefor it'd be off-topic? If that's the reason, I can stand behind it. It just feels a bit complex to get to that reasoning, but it checks out.

Comment: @Lilienthal Which reason for topicality would that have fallen under?

Comment: @ChristopherEstep The same one since in that case it falls under sentence 1: Ask your manager/HR why your title is incorrect. We can't guess whether it's a simple mistake, a default setting or if they're doing it deliberately. Only people at his company know that.

Comment: @Migz It's just a bit of an XY problem. OP is saying "*they're not giving me the title I was promised, should I complain now or argue for a 'better' title at my evaluation?*". But that's pure guesswork and the first step here is to figure out what's actually going on. And then the answer becomes "Ask HR/your manager" and we close those questions because they're useless for Q&A and there really isn't any way for answers to be functionally different from each other. The main problem I saw with the question is that no one seems to have pointed this out to the OP.