# Reopen "How to convince manager to let employees change departments?"

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I would like to reopen the question

[How to convince manager to let employees change departments?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/85845/how-to-convince-manager-to-let-employees-change-departments)

Right now it is closed for [seeking advice on company-specific regulations](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694). That close reason is intended for questions about how to interpret specific company policy. This question is asking about *how to talk to a manager* about changing a policy. Regardless of whether you think the OP should take this action or not, the question is fundamentally different and should be reopened.

Comment: I see your point; you should edit it to be more general and you might get more tractions.

Comment: @user30031 How would you suggest generalizing it

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend it :)