# Reopen question on forwarding emails to personal address in the UK

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

This question ([HR and work emails forwarded to private email - can they be used in a court of law?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/90555/40085)) has been put on hold for being company-specific.

However, the question is not company-specific because in the UK, companies don't get to define grievance procedures. There is a standard best practice which is legally binding.

Can this question be reopened?

Comment: I have edited your post to be a reopen-request rather than a close-complaint. I do not necessarily agree with it (yet) because this "Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals." is also a part of the close reason. I am not familiar with the UK work practices, but if you can confirm that this question is "what does the law say on this?" and not, "help, I need free lawyer online", then I will gladly cast a reopen vote.

Comment: Generally questions related to gathering submittable evidence for a legal claim are beyond the scope of this site. That's where you talk to a lawyer, not the internet.

Comment: @Lilienthal its not strictly about valid evidence in the legal sense  employment law in the UK  is not like some America legal tv show. As an experienced Lay Union officer I have never heard of emails or company documents being challenged at an employment  tribunal

Comment: [The close reason for legal is pretty clear](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694). If this question was re-opened under it's current context, I would VTC as requesting legal advice. The meta states: *Questions should be able to be answered by an HR professional in another company, and shouldn't require specific legal expertise*

Comment: @Draken If the grievance procedure is standard throughout the country, and is not company-specific, then I think an HR professional from another company could be expected to know the procedure. That said though, I would not go out on a limb to reopen this question, with the currently available information.

Comment: @MaskedMan As someone who has lived and worked in the UK, confidentiality of documents and whether they can be used in a court case are a very company specific policy. If they're are checking if they can legally use the documents, then they need a lawyer. If they need a lawyer, then VTC. It's asking far too much on the side of what is usable in a court of law and that would have to be figured out between the lawyer and the company's confidentially rules.

Comment: @Draken I see, thanks. Then I agree with keeping the question closed.

Comment: @Draken discoverability and chain of evidence  in was never covered by any of my training you or any of the case law notes that the TUC and employment lawyers put out. You might be confusing criminal law here - I am formally accredited to represent people in grievance and discipline cases BTW

Comment: The OP, in the question at the moment, is asking what can and cannot be used in a court of law. You need some legal advice to be able to tell that for definite. You can deal with grievance procedures, but doesn'T mean you can dictate whether it it legal to take documentation that is under legal contract to a court case. Hence needing a lawyer and hence leaving the question closed. If it didn't reference a court or legality, I can understand opening it, but in it's current state, we'd just get lots of people stating IANAL and giving their rubbish advice.

Comment: @Draken I take the point but to be blunt unless your a test case (supported by a trade union) or a banker on 10 mill a year your never going to be in a "legal" court for an employment issue - 99.99% of disputes are settled in the Tribunal system.