# Update Help Center to match new off-topic wordings

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, help-center

We recently changed the "advice on what to do" close reason to "[advice on a specific choice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/16983)". However, I noticed that the off-topic definitions in the [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) were not updated to match the new wording. Can this be changed? I also think that the "focusing on ranting" could be updated to match the current "[questions require a goal](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696)".

Are there any other places these definitions show up that we might have missed?

Comment: I see that the problem you mentioned still persists, any updates regarding this question?

Comment: @GrayCygnus Not yet. I was going to give it a week then flag the question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has been updated.

### Before

> ### What questions are off topic here?
>
> - [Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or
>   policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694)
> - [Questions asking for advice on what to do](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) (including
>   [reviewing resumes, CVs, cover letters,
>   e-mails](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596), asking for
>   [legal
>   advice](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice),
>   as well as [specific salaries, billing rates, market
>   worth](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for),
>   etc.)
> - [Questions that focus on ranting about problems rather than trying to solve them](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696)
> - [Questions that aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (see also
>   [Good Subjective, Bad
>   Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
>   for information on how to ask a subjective question suitable for the
>   Stack Exchange format)

### After

> ### What questions are off topic here?
>
> - Questions seeking [**company-specific advice**](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694) on workplace
>   regulations or policies, or [**legal
>   advice**](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice)
> - Questions that [**lack a clear goal we can address**](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) or focus on
>   ranting about problems rather than trying to solve them
> - Questions asking for [**advice on a specific choice**](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) (including
>   [reviewing resumes, CVs, cover letters,
>   e-mails](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2596), as well as
>   [specific salaries, billing rates, market
>   worth](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for),
>   etc.)
> - Questions [**that aren't a good fit** for the Stack Exchange format](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (see also
>   [Good Subjective, Bad
>   Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
>   for information on how to ask a subjective question suitable for the
>   Stack Exchange format)