# Give more info around the site on how to make a question less company specific

Tags: discussion, flagging, offtopic, help-center

I see you already have [a meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2694/34374) explaining how to edit a question to remove "company specific" elements. I understand this rule is to prevent questions and answers which are only helpful to the OP, however I imagine a great deal of people coming here will have questions which are at their core "company specific", but it's likely possible to be able to make them more generalised.

As this is *the* place for getting help with company related matters in the workplace, it would be good to focus on steering people down the right path with regards "company specific". This helps the OP, others seeking guidance, and the site having less moderation to do (etc).

So I have a couple of suggestions:

**Tweak the rule to give a little advice to what is a complicated off topic rule with grey areas:**

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> Questions seeking company-specific advice on workplace regulations or
>   policies, or legal advice. *Instead, make your question more generalised so
>   it's useful to future visitors. [Read more about it here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2694/34374)*

I know reading all the rules makes them all clear as a whole, but I think it'd be beneficial for this specific rule being made more clear in more areas.

I think when you've been here a while and have absorbed how everything works it's easy to feel such things are obvious, but often they're not, or at least how to work with specific rules.

I also suggest adding the link to the "company specific" meta help answer in the "off topic" flag, and perhaps tweaking it slightly to explain questions can be ok if less localised. Currently it just advises speaking with the manager, which just pushes them away:

Currently:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements,
>   or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department.
>   Questions that address only a specific company or position are of
>   limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should
>   be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here.

I suggest something like:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements,
>   or policies are not answerable or are of limited use to future
>   visitors. You can edit the question to remove company specific
>   elements and make it more generalised. [Read more about it here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2694/34374).
>   Otherwise your question should be directed to your manager or HR
>   department.

Also note that I removed the legal close reason.
You don't have many off topic close flags at preset, and it's more logical to close for "this is company specific" OR "we don't answer legal stuff", but both in one close message sends mixed messages.

This allows the off topic message about "company related" to be more precise and informative, and perhaps a little more info on the separate legal close reason, to also make it more informative and not paired with an unrelated close reason.

I get that this is a substantial change being suggested.

**The "On Topic" rules state:**

> Leadership in the workplace (motivating people, encouraging people,
>   making decisions, holding hard conversations, intervening in
>   unproductive situations, asking for and giving help)

Most of those allowed topics above have the potential to be "company-specific" (off topic rule), and there will be many people wanting help with the above "On Topic" items where they ask in a way it's localised to their company.
So the suggestions may help bring about good questions from those areas which otherwise would have just been shut down for being off topic.

**Try to fix them:**

I'm sure many people do, I'm just bringing the point up here as it's entirely relevant.

A question being "company specific" doesn't mean it cannot be rescued rather than closed. If there's not a current obvious dupe, look to see if the question can be edited to easily remove the localisation of the problem from a company specific issue. And generalise the question so answers would help others in other scenarios.

Obviously this wont always be possible, or will be too much work.

With the question and title made more generic, answers can be given that'd help many people. And instead of just closing new questions that are "company specific", they can now be duped with the relevant Q&A that you made generic.

This will build up a solid collection of Q&As and various scenarios indexed and searchable leading to the same great answers. This also helps stop people raising dupes, which they may do when a previous similar one is closed, rather than duped to a question that answers theirs too so their can also be duped.