# Getting downvotes and delete votes for my recent questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes

A couple of my recent questions have gotten a lot of downvotes and delete votes for each - the questions are:

[Is it rude and unprofessional for a hiring manager to check with my references before deciding whether to make the verbal offer official?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119440/is-it-rude-and-unprofessional-for-a-hiring-manager-to-check-with-my-references-b)

[Offer downgraded to temp-to-perm, from permanent - how should I proceed?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/119447/offer-downgraded-to-temp-to-perm-from-permanent-how-should-i-proceed)

I sense some hostility on this forum, although I'm not sure why though - I'm not on here much.

Are my questions actually bad quality?  If so, how can I improve them?

Is there a moderator that can look into this?

Thanks to Joe and others who have taken the time to write great answers and leave valuable comments to my questions.

Comment: It's only -8 and -4, that's hardly worth worrying about, I routinely get more than that in downvotes

Comment: @Kilisi *down votes comment*

Comment: How do you get from "check references prior to offer" to "extreme micromanager?" That seems like a pretty big logical leap. Perhaps you'd get more insightful answers if you explain why you believe this to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a moderator that can look into this?

Remember that if you need to raise a post to Mod attention you can always flag for such, or see if anyone is in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler).

> Are my questions actually bad quality? If so, how can I improve them?

I actually answered one of those posts, so I do consider that one answerable. Perhaps it was not the best phrasing you could make, but it surely wasn't terrible.

A suggestion, **avoid using *"Should I"* on your posts**, as that tends to attract votes to close as most of the time it ends up being an off-topic question (because it's basically asking for us to make a choice, which is [off-topic for the site](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/73791)).

Now, regarding the other post (the reference one) I am clueless why so many downvotes...

It was closed because it seems the question was asked before, and thus closed as duplicate. However, the -6 votes seem a bit exaggerated. Still, [the reasons for why users Downvote are unknown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/332286), so don't worry much about it.

If you ever **feel hostility or that something is not ok feel free to Mod Flag**, or ask in chat or here as you did now. Sorry if this was your first impressions on the site, I assure you this is not the standard here :)

Comment: The reference one was probably downvoted because it reads like a rant looking for confirmation rather than an honest question looking for an unbiased answer.

Comment: @Kevin that is also a valid point. Sometimes it's better to let things cool down before posting

Answer (score 5):

Moderators can't do anything about downvotes - that's the community at work.

However, if you want someone to look into the voting behaviour, then you can use the ["contact us"](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form  to ask the community team (the level above diamond moderators) if you appear to be a victim of targeted downvoting.

The reason for your -6 score seems fairly self-apparent if you look at the linked duplicate which points out that it's quite normal practice to ask for references before being handed a formal offer.  Unfortunately, questions that are common-knowledge in nature tend to collect downvotes (since the answer would have been apparent given some research).  And suggesting that the hiring manager is "rude and unprofessional" does seem to be inviting negativity.

In your other question, you're asking us to help you make a rather opinion-based career decision, for which we have a specific close reason.  We can't make life decisions for people in this way because there's so many variables to take into account.

However, people do answer these kinds of questions because they have some advice to impart.  While it's great that people want to help, leaving this kind of question open can result in answers offering wildly different advice.

Comment: Just to expand on this - `Moderators can't do anything about downvotes - that's the community at work.` - we _cannot_ do anything because we cannot see votes. The only people who can take a serious look into voting are Stack Exchange employees, as moderators we have a very _very_ limited insight into such things. I'm hesitant to even say we have any insight given how limited our visibility is

Comment: Yes, this.  I basically meant that we can't prevent people from downvoting a question or answers.  People are free to spend their votes how they wish, as long as it's not in a targetted way.