# Is this the right stack exchange to ask questions for learning current good manufacturing practices?

Tags: discussion

I am a biology major who is applying for QC laboratory jobs, which state the need for cGMP skills. I am having trouble honing down resources for learning cGMP, as I hear it is variable to your job.

What is the best way to go about learning cGMP (virology or cell biology) and is this the right stack exchange to ask this question?

Comment: "Questions asking for **advice on a specific choice**, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or for more specific details about one element of the decision. ([More information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2693#2695))..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we can't help you find resources specific to your job and field. We're much more about general workplace questions that could apply to almost any field.

I see you've already asked about your question [on Biology Meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3900/question-about-learning-virology-for-industry), which is a great place to start. If they can't help you, you can try asking on the main Meta using the [site-recommendation tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation). Unfortunately, it may turn out that there is no good place for your question on SE. We cover a lot of topics, but we can't do it all!

Answer (score 4):

The Biology site has an active [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere).  You might want to drop in there and ask the question there.

You might get some advice in chat, and you might get guidance on how to ask a relevant question either on the site there, or Meta.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of borderline, but we have too few users with any experience to be able to guide you.

We can guide you for general workplace practices, however.