# Should I cancel contact with a contract hiring agency; is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I feel this question might be a duplicate, but if it isn't is it on topic to post?

> I was contacted for contract work by a contract agency for a company I really wanted to work for as a full time employee. However since I also applied for an actual job, I was quickly contacted for an official position with the company as well after I notified them of this.
>
> I finished an interview and I called a HR person today about if I had the position. She said she was 90% sure and was going to get back to me today. They are very swamped with hiring right now apparently. However, she also wanted me to cancel contact via an email or other means with the contract company for the other available position for that same company.
>
> What should I do in this case? I want to work for the company but don't want to ruin any chance. 90% is not 100% and I don't have an official offer yet.

Comment: Just to confirm; have you actually did a cautionary search for duplicates yet? Even if it's worded slightly different, a search or two should help identify if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel this question might be a duplicate, but if it isn't is it on topic to post?

If you feel it might be a duplicate the best thing to do is to browse the posts we have and see if a question there answers your inquiries.

Even if you didn't find it, and posted it anyways, you will still get answer and perhaps someone will link you to the duplicate you didn't find (if any).

Reading your post, it seems to me workplace-related... however asking *"What should I do?"* is off-topic for this site (as it is asking for us to make a [choice](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/73791) for OP, and also lacks an explicit [goal](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/73791)).

If you work on that aspect, and rephrase the question asked to make it on topic and include a goal we can help you achieve, then I would say you can go and post it.