# Can this question be asked around here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Once I was notified from my management that I had been part of some injustice against some woman and therefore I am no longer welcome to do business with them. My manager asked me what it was but I could only guess. I tried to ask colleagues if there was some rumour about such an event of if somebody could confirm what it was. We still don't know more about it. I have tried to have the claim investigated and the people I speak with can also only speculate what it was. I was told by the authorities and also colleagues that it is an "anti-pattern" and if I actually was unfair somewhere then the right thing to do would be to inform me so that I could apologize or regret what I did. But now I am cynic and angry that nobody even confirmed or told me who, what, where, when. Only why: That I had been unfair completely unspecified.

Comment: you can't do business with your management? Or they sacking you?

Comment: I think that is besides the point, and why ask? Let's say they sacked me. Or that they didn't and I just changed my location and kept the employment. What is the recommendation to do, both for a management and for the accused in case of horrible accusations of this kind?

Comment: I asked because I don't understand the question... never heard of can't do business with management.... unclear why one manager says this other know nothing about it but won't do business with you... what does that mean?

Comment: We think it is revenge against me but that is also speculation.

Comment: I don't understand the whole question sorry. You need to make it clearer.

Comment: How to deal with a "workplace-related" event when nobody knows what it is.

Comment: ["Questions require a goal that we can address..."](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/168)

Comment: @gnat One goal used to be called "justice" wasn't it? We think that we should handle cases of blaming and situations which seem like Franz Kafka. How to deal with situations and people who break their own rules.

Comment: This isn’t a question.

Comment: @mxyzplk But it must have been. Or how do you know "this"? Let's find out what the question has been from the beginning in this confusing matter. Did (s)he or did (s)he not.... what?

Comment: The paragraph you have written above is not a question.  It is a gripe.  It has no question for anyone to answer.  It would be closed as “questions require a goal we can address.”

Comment: @mxyzplk What you have written is splitting hairs. The situation needs recommendations and a question of what is relevant.

Comment: You can listen or not listen, but if you post this it’ll be closed.

Comment: @mxyzplk Question: "How can I be found guilty of injustice related to a workplace?" Is that good enough? Bosses absolutely claim that is question today. You may disagree of course...

Answer (score 2):

I can see two main things that I don't think would be received well:

- You say your management notified you that you *"had been part of some injustice against some woman"*, and then that they asked you what it was. That's really confusing. I think you mean that you were fired but not really told why, but I'm not confident about that. It will be helpful to your question if you make that part clearer.
- The initial version of your text doesn't contain an actual question, just a description of the situation you're in. You say in the comments that your goal is to find out *"How to deal with a "workplace-related" event when nobody knows what it is"*. That should be in your question post, otherwise it will attract close votes (as gnat alluded to in the comments).

I'd also suggest you add paragraphs and trim the "story" part a bit, to leave only the most high level points. It may still get closed as off-topic or a duplicate, but I think there's a good question in there.

Maybe something like:

> I was called into a meeting by my management, told that I had been part of an injustice against a woman, and fired. **[I'm guessing that's what you meant - change as appropriate]**. During the meeting my manager would not tell me what it was, and said that I should know already. **[This is absolute speculation on my part, but it seems like it might be what happened? Change it to the real story, but keep it short]**
>   
>   I have been unable to find out what they were referring to, and my efforts have only been met with speculation. I've also been told that if I actually was unfair somewhere then the right thing to do would be to inform me so that I could apologize and make amends for what I did. **[I believe my change to your wording here is important. If you write as if you want to dismiss any real wrongdoing (if it turns out it existed) then people are likely to focus on that.]**
>   
>   I am cynical and angry that nobody even confirmed or told me who, what, where, when. How can I move on from an event like this? **[ <-This last sentence is where you need to specify your goal. The one I've written isn't very good, and would likely get closed as "too broad". You need to specify what you want to achieve, as specifically as you can]**

Comment: Can't we just say the simple truth that I was told over the phone that I was guilty of injustice towards a woman. And then examine what it could have been. Regardless of being "fired", it is some statement of injustice against some woman. But we believe that I had the right to know what it was. Many people are confused and you make it even more complicated when we mix in more and more legal issues.

Comment: Yes you could. The fewer parts to the story there are the less confusing it will be, so the better people will receive it.

Comment: All this is just based on my own observations of the site of course. This is all advice, not a guarantee :)