# Is my question about a reasonable pay rate request a duplicate of another question stating how to find a reasonable pay rate for a job?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I'm not entirely sure if a recommended duplicate actually answers the question I'm asking.

[My question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/152030/how-much-higher-should-i-go-than-my-current-salary-when-negotiating-for-pay/152031#152031) is asking for specifics on how to ask for a higher pay at a new position than I have at my current one, while the [suggested duplicate](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for) is about generally finding out if a pay rate is reasonable for a given position.

The latter is specific to finding a reasonable rate for a given job, whereas the former is more specifically trying to suss out if asking for a higher rate that still resides within the median job rate range is reasonable.

I personally don't feel like my question is answered completely, because I'm looking to find out if there's a reasonable amount to ask above my current pay rate, where the duplicate is only providing an answer for finding the rate for a job when you don't already know it - something that I already researched.

Would the second question be reasonably considered a duplicate?  Or is my question specific enough to warrant a second question on the site?

Answer (score 3):

> Would the second question be reasonably considered a duplicate?

The target duplicate is in fact a very good post which contains several good answers that give suggestions on the process of determining a salary to ask for.

It seems that such thing is what you are asking, and thus a valid target IMHO.

> Or is my question specific enough to warrant a second question on the site?

Currently, IMHO, the question you ask is off-topic, as it is asking us to make a choice for you (if you *should* negotiate or not is up to you, as well as what type of increase *should* you ask for).

Your question would be on-topic if you removed the choice from your question... but if you do that, you end up with an exact duplicate of the post suggested... so...

Seems to me that the duplicate suggested is valid and is a post you should consider reading as it will be beneficial to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for this through explanation - I hadn't considered that the question of what choice I should make is off-topic, and that being the case, the remaining portion of my question *would* be a duplicate.

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: See: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/73791 for the off topic reason I described