# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I don't understand why my most recent question ([Feeling exhausted and disheartened while working on my current assignment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182565/feeling-exhausted-and-disheartened-while-working-on-my-current-assignment)) has received downvotes. How can I improve it further?

Comment: Looking through this, I suspect it's because it's a type of post we see here quite often, in that it's mostly describing your situation and how you find it challenging without really being explicit about what you're after: getting up to speed faster, talking to your boss about more help, etc. We often close such questions because they lack a clear way for them to be answered. More on that here : [Custom Off-Topic Close Reasons Change](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696)

Comment: Best way to improve would be to focus on what you're after *and* edit the question down for length. You could ask about how to get more concrete/actionable feedback from your boss, that would be the most productive angle I see. Other questions you could ask such as how to judge your performance, how to deal with inadequate training, etc. are all mostly secondary as for your specific situation you need to first figure out whether your boss is happy with where you are or not. That's the question I'd ask if I were you. You can either edit the current question or post a new one.

Comment: An alternative question would be around the feeling you have of not being where you think you should be 6 months in. Though the answers there would still amount to "talk to your boss first" to see if this is a 'you' thing or if there's really a performance issue.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thank you for the advice. I shall try to incorporate your suggestions into my answer.

Comment: I have edited my question