# "Advice on what to do" close reason is over-broad

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

**Update:** We asked this question almost two years ago, and it took a while for voting to produce a clear winner.  We'd like to implement [this answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3290/325).

As described [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3181/325), I feel the current wording of one of our close reasons is misleading:

> Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I learn?"). Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do. For more information, click here.

*All* questions, fundamentally, are asking for "advice on what to do".  The trick is in how you refine them.  "Here's my tale of woe; help!" doesn't work, and broad "what would you do?" opinion surveys don't work.  The key info in this close reason is in the examples -- what job to take, what skills to learn, etc -- rather than in the first phrase that people see.

I just came across a wording we used to use (found in an old, closed question):

> Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else.

That's much better.  Apparently we found it too restrictive and broadened it, but I think we went too far.  Can we find something in the middle?

**What wording should this close reason have that is sufficiently inclusive but not too broad?**

Also, bear in mind that "primarily opinion-based" is baked into SE; that option already exists.

Comment: if memory serves, intent was to make it easier to see how to edit the question to prevent close or to reopen. You edit out "what should I do" and after that, try to make sense of what remains - and, if you can make it, question is worthy of staying open (I didn't actively participate in wording this, so I may miss something)

Comment: I've always thought we should not include the phrase "What do I do?" when explaining the reason to close. I come across so many questions that clearly state the problem and the desired outcome but finish with "What do I do [to achieve what I have just explained]?" These questions almost always get a few close votes just for having that specific wording at the end, even though they meet our standards.

Comment: For some context why that close reason exists: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2693/16

Comment: Another for Context: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/good-subjective-bad-subjective-and-agony-aunt-questions

Comment: I think the general consensus is that this close reason should change, though we maybe haven't settled on a particular wording. (My current favorite is Chad's.) I'm guessing the mods need to take the next steps? I just want to make sure this doesn't drift away and get forgotten before action gets taken.

Comment: When I first came to this SE site, I couldn't help but notice that 99% of the questions violate at least the letter of that rule... as written.

Comment: Per the update, I'm totally on board with this!

Comment: This question should be closed as it's asking for advice on what to do...

Comment: Thanks for updating this Monica! Slight grammar nitpick - I think the last line should be "asking how to make the decision, or ***for*** more specific details"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about:

> Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are off-topic as the answers are unlikely to be useful for anyone else, and are often primarily opinion-based.  Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or more specific details about one element of the decision.

Keeping a *little* bit of the breadth I think is helpful, as otherwise people will think it only applies to the listed points (yes, 'etc.' is there, but giving some clarification on what 'etc.' means is useful).

I also think that the 'rarely useful to anyone else' is less important than the 'opinion based' side: we answer all sorts of questions that wouldn't necessarily be very useful for other people on StackExchange sites, but in these cases it's really that there is not a good answer possible: it comes down to opinion and preference.

---

**Moderator note:** At this writing this answer is +30/-1, so we're going with it.  I did some minor wordsmithing to prioritize "too subjective" over "not useful to others" and to make room for a meta link.  Here's the final version:

> Questions asking for **advice on a specific career choice**, such as what job to take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to make, try asking how to make the decision, or more specific details about one element of the decision. ([More information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/325))

**Further Update:**
This close reason has been modified again:

> Questions asking for advice on a specific choice, such as what job to
>   take or what skills to learn, are difficult to answer objectively and
>   are rarely useful for anyone else. Instead of asking which decision to
>   make, try asking how to make the decision, or more specific details
>   about one element of the decision.

[More Information](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4711/16)

Comment: Nice!  I like this wording.

Comment: This is much, much better than the current version.

Comment: The final sentence doesn't flow smoothly. I'd suggest something like `Instead of asking what decision to make, try asking how you should come to a decision or narrow your question down to specific elements of the decision.`

Comment: I like this too!

Comment: If Lilienthal's version of the last sentence is preferred that's fine - I have no preference.

Comment: This wording implies that "advice on a specific choice" is an accurate summary of what's problematic with these questions, which seems like it would include every question on the site (i.e. the same problem as the current phrasing). If it was made more precise like "advice on a specific long-term career development choice" then I'd support this.

Comment: This close reason loses the close for the general here is my situation tell me what to do questions that the current close reason is intended to include.  Perhaps rewording "Instead of asking which decision to make" to "Instead of asking what/which decision to make" will make it clear that those questions are not appropriate but im not sure.

Comment: @ReallyTiredOfThisGame I'd probably be tempted to close "here is my tale of woe; what do I do?" as either "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based", depending on the specific content of the question.  That sort of question isn't on-topic *anywhere* on SE that I'm aware of, so maybe the general reasons work?  (Just thinking out loud here.)

Comment: We wanted them declared specifically off topic though.

Comment: Why?  All close reasons say "doesn't fit here"; if an SE-wide reason applies, why does our close reason need to be specifically an *off-topic* reason?  "Here is my situation; what do I do?" is closed all over the network as unanswerable, but most sites haven't made custom off-topic reasons for it as far as I know.

Comment: @MonicaCellio because they were a problem that is effectively dealt with this way.  Read the linked threads above.

Comment: @really I disagree with "effectively". Have you read the many comments on those questions about this reason?  You can also prevent poor questions by allowing none, but that would obviously be overkill. I say this reason is overkill and the built-in reasons apply to those not covered by a new wording here.  It looks like the community agrees, so barring a *compelling* argument we will probably change this.

Comment: Well the IMO the mods should be culling comments far more agressively.  If their comments dissappear people will stop chatting in comments. And while we have more of a comment problem we have far less of a question problem.  And even the comments are not as bad as they have been.

Comment: I like this wording a lot - it gets at the core of why these questions are a problem ("tell me what to do") but doesn't stop "tell me what to do _to accomplish this goal_" which is great. The difficult questions are when people ask us to make a decision for them. Which are nearly impossible to answer, since there are always more factors which are unknown and yet is required for a good answer.

Comment: I can think of no better phrasing.

Comment: (1) Most questions relate to a specific choice, this has the same problem as the original reason. (2) I'm not sure a question like "what job to take" can really be fixed by simply asking how to make the decision instead (e.g. "how do I compare these job"), as this phrasing seems to imply - I feel like the "Instead of" part should be removed.

Comment: *or more specific details about one element of the decision.*  - This wording is unclear to mean what is intended by this.  I think this wording needs to be clarified before implementing this.

Comment: It should not be limitied to career choices.  I find this last minute stealth change to be unacceptable.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Please provide a link to where the new wording that limited the close reason to career choices was discussed?

Comment: Are you objecting to the word *career*?  That suggestion came from [this recent answer](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4648/325), which didn't garner any opposition and seemed uncontroversial, and examples, and what we actually use it for.  If it's a big deal to you I don't mind removing that one word; just get two mods to edit it (changes to close reasons require two mods).  I won't be able to help for a while.  (If you'd skipped the nonconstructive commentary and accusations on a completely different site and said what you actually object to earlier, I could have helped then.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio - It had 3 votes vs 30 for the one without... i thought the community decision would be clear.  What I think would be the best course would be to remove the word career from the close reason for now.  If you really think it should be limited to career start a new topic to limit the close reason to only career choices...  So we can get a community consensus

Comment: Not a fan. This is a 2 year old question. It would have made more sense to ask it again and let the current community discuss it rather than play necromancer to a topic and make a decision. I'd rather it go back the way it was and revisit the topic with a new discussion, since it wasn't compelling enough to change back then. I find changing something based on something suggested 2 years ago to be ... bizarre

Comment: @chris Chad we updated and featured the  question 2 weeks ago saying we wanted to do this. The career suggestion cane after that and as I said seemed ok - I wouldn't expect 30 votes  in that time. This one took 2 years to get there. Removing career is ok but I see no reason to completely revert.

Comment: "details about one element of the decision" Is even more specific than "advice on a specific choice". These two elements seem counteracting each other.

Answer (score 11):

#### My proposal:

> It is not practical for us to answer a question that depends so heavily on your own abilities, preferences or circumstances. Instead, consider asking a factual question that will help you make your own choices, and that can be answered without detailed knowledge of your personal situation.

#### Rationale:

**A good close reason focusses on why the question is unsuitable for this site, and suggests an alternative (where one exists).** If it focusses on the wrong thing, it can be both too restrictive and too broad.

**Putting topics or forms of words in the close reason** (as opposed to the comments or guidance page where they can be contextualised) **risks misleading close-voters** (into closing things they shouldn't, and possibly ignoring other questions which have the same problem but don't fit the mould) **and question authors** (it doesn't help them fix the question or ask better questions in the future), **unless those topics/phrases are outright prohibited on their own account** (e.g. belongs on another SE site, we are not lawyers, etc.).

It's possible to have good questions which - implicitly or explicitly - ask what to do, what skills to learn, what job to take, but which are sufficiently focussed and convey enough information that the question answerable and the answer is applicable to others.

The real problem questions are generally asking for **personalised career advice**, which results in some combination of:

- asking the OP loads of detailed questions about what they actually want (which of these incentives is more important to you?)
- finding out what the OP's tolerance of a range of different risks is (how happy are you trading away all job security?), which may depend on the financial position of the OP (household savings, etc.)
- assessing the OP's abilities (which skill are you better at, and by how much?)
- determining if certain factors exist which the OP has ommitted (is your company currently short-staffed or looking to reduce its headcount?)

For every Question proper, we end up firing two or three questions back (or writing flowchart answers in which we try to give all possible answers and the circumstances in which they're appropriate).

Quite often the OP doesn't rightly know themselves, and even if we give them a satisfactory answer, we only get it 'right' for that one person's situation.

A good-fit question will elicit answers which are useful to someone else, which means someone else needs to read the question and be able to confidently say either "I am in the same boat" - or not.

Comment: I think I really like this.  I fear that some will think this also over broad but I think it is exactly what we need.

Comment: I like this too.

Comment: I like how this is short yet covers this close reason very well. One nitpick, I'm admittedly not a native speaker but "Consider instead asking" feels like an unnatural construct, wouldn't "Instead, consider asking" be preferable? It also scans better and makes it clear that sentence is what the OP should do to improve the question.

Comment: Lilienthal: done, thanks.

Comment: You might want to remove "or circumstances" from this (and rephrase "your personal situation" in some manner), as most on-topic questions depend heavily on the asker's circumstances (and personal situation).

Comment: Of course this could also be phrased like: `"Questions that depend exclusively on one's own abilities and preferences (e.g. ...) are off topic because ..."`.

Comment: "abilities, preferences or motivations" maybe?

Comment: This option has my vote.

Answer (score 3):

My proposal:

> Questions seeking advice on what job to take, what skills to learn, etc. are off-topic as the answers are rarely useful to anyone else. Instead of asking what decision to make, try asking how to make a decision.  For more information click here.

The "here" link would point to something very similar to [the current one](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/325), maybe even an edit to that.  The *reasoning* is the same; it's just the presentation that I think is a problem.  That post should probably also link to [this help](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I think it's a good improvement.  I sort of wonder if we should include that asking "What should I do?" is _not_ what we can answer but rather, "How can I make an informed decision?"

Comment: Not just rarely useful to anyone else, but also rarely answerable without going into far more detailed analysis of this person's hopes fears, likes and dislikes, skills, and so on than we could possibly address here.

Comment: This reason was changed a year or so ago with the intent of encompassing the general here is my problem tell me what to do questions.  This would remove that part.  I have always disliked the wording on the close reason, but I also hate to see that portion removed.

Answer (score 2):

I Suggest:

> Questions asking for advice on what decision(s) to make, are not
>   practical answerable questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or
>   "what skills should I learn?"). Questions should get answers
>   explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what
>   decisions to make or course to take. For more information click here.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

> Questions asking for advice specific to one's own career path ("what job should I take?", "what skills should I learn?", etc.) are off-topic as it can be difficult to give objective advice to such questions and the answers are rarely applicable to a broader audience.

This can also be phrased like:

> Questions asking for advice relating to career path decisions (...) ...

---

There *may* be questions not falling under "career path decisions" (currently) commonly closed using this reason, but these can either:

- Just be closed as opinion-based instead.
- Be edited to be on topic.

The reason I think career path decisions should be singled out here is because they are fundamentally outside of the scope of this site (right?) - it's often impossible for such questions to be edited to be on topic by the author or anyone else, even if one can come up with some more objective version of the question.

The rest are just opinion-based and trying to have this close reason cover all of those when we already have a reason for that just seems counter-productive.

Comment: Thanks for this contribution.  I added "career" to the final version (see the accepted answer for the full text).